# JavaScript Function Strangeness

Tags: javascript, arrays

In JavaScript, while declaring a variable like this:

```
let something = arr.push()
```

Why the array behave like calling the push method like 'arr.push()'?

Answer (score 3):

> why the array behave like calling the push method like 'arr.push()'.

Because that's exactly what the code does. It **calls** `arr.push()`, and then assigns its return value (the new length of the array) to `something`, exactly the way `x = foo()` **calls** `foo` and assigns its return value to `x`.

If you wanted to assign the function itself to `something`, you wouldn't use the `()` at the end:

```
let something = arr.push;
```

You could later push to the array like this:

```
something.call(arr, valueToPush);
```

The `.call(arr,` part of that is there so that `this` during the call refers to the array `arr` refers to, since `push` uses `this`. If you wanted to avoid that, you could use `bind` to bind `arr` to the function:

```
let something = arr.push.bind(arr);
```

Then this would work:

```
something(valueToPush);
```

Answer (score 1):

`arr.push()` returns the new length of the array while pushing the value into the array